# Interpretation of residual variance and corrleation in factor analysis

Tags: regression, correlation, residuals, factor-analysis, structural-equation-modeling

[image]

Hi!

The above image is from "Latent Variable Models" by Loehlin and Beaujean (p.146).

It's a four group-model, with male idential twins, female idential twins, male fraternal twins, and female fraternal twins.

The latent variable Num1 refers to the numerical ability of "twin 1", and Num2 belongs to "twin 2."

The same goes for the manifest variables.

The four group only differ in their covariance between Num1 and Num2 (for identital twins it's 1, and fraternal twins it's 0.5).

The both latent variables are standardized.

Also, corresponding residual covariances were considered to be equal (for example, the cov between Ad and Mu is same for both of the twins).

Given the model above, the authors created the following table.

[image]

First, the "Other shared variance - cross-twin within-trait residual correlation" for the Addition in the third column is defined as follow.

$r$ is the residual variance of both Ad1 and Ad2.

$s$ is the residual covariance between Ad1 and Ad2.

$vAD$ is the variance of both Ad1 and Ad2, defined as $a^2 + r$.

And its "Other shared variance - cross-twin within-trait residual correlation" is

$$\frac{s}{\sqrt{vAD}*\sqrt{vAD}} = 0.147$$

What is it? I'm lost here.

But I know that it is not the residual correlation between Ad1 and Ad2.

Because the residual correlation between Ad1 and Ad2 should be defined as follow.

$$\frac{s}{\sqrt{r}*\sqrt{r}}$$

Why divide the residual covariance between Ad1 and Ad2 by standard deviation of Ad1 and Ad2, not their residual sd?

Also, For the residual correlation part for Ad-Mu, the followings were calculated.

"other shared correlation---cross-person cross-trait residual covariance" (when $e1$ is the residual covariance b/t Ad1-Mu2 and Ad2-Mu1)

$$AD.MU.cpct = \frac{e1}{\sqrt{vAD}*\sqrt{vMU}} = 0.059$$

"environmental contributions to correlations--within-person cross-trait residual correlation" (when $d$ is the residual covariance b/t Ad1-Mu1 and Ad2-Mu2)

$$AD.MU.wpct = \frac{d}{\sqrt{vAD}*\sqrt{vMU}} = 0.144$$

And the "residual correlations" are calculated as follow.

$$rAD.MU = AD.MU.wpct - AD.MU.cpct = 0.087$$

I have no idea what they are too.

Also Why the last three components together equal the phenotypic correlation (0.55 + 0.06 + 0.09 = 0.7)?

This model has been killing me for days.

I would really appreciate any help!